# How to ask to let you pass in the bus

Tags: american-english, politeness

For example, you are sitting near the window on the bus.  A person sits next to you and blocks the passage (not on purpose).

And here is your stop and you need to get out.  How to ask politely to let you pass?

(North America if that matters)

Comment: Usually if you stand up, they know you want to pass. You can also say 'Excuse me', which is a normal way to ask someone to allow you to pass.